# Outputting a string of HTML

Tags: php

I'm adding my HTML to a var:

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<li>';
$html .= '<p>hello</p>';
$html .= '</li>';
....
echo $html
```

When I view the page's source the above is all output on one line. How can I fix it so that we see the layout as you would if it was written:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>hello</p>
    </li>
    ...
```

Comment: You would add the spaces/tabs yourself, does it really matter if the output is indented? - Browsers don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add newlines with `\n` and tabs with `\t`:

```
$html = '';
$html .= "<li>\n";
$html .= "\t<p>hello</p>\n";
$html .= "</li>\n";
```

Comment: If you're going to store this string in a file then it's better to use `PHP_EOL` rather than `\n` otherwise `\n` is better.

Answer (score 2):

Could always do this:

```
?>
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>hello</p>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php
```

BUT keep in mind that there is an important difference between "all mashed together" and "nicely spaced out": whitespace will cause empty text nodes to be added, which may interfere with layouts (if using `display:inline-block`) or JavaScript (if using `childNodes`). It also takes up extra unnecessary bandwidth. Use what is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all at once:

```
$html = '
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>hello</p>
    </li>
</ul>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP constant PHP_EOL.

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<li>' . PHP_EOL;
$html .= '<p>hello</p>' . PHP_EOL;
$html .= '</li>' . PHP_EOL;
```